# Redirect queries from one entity to another using c# / entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is a bit of a puzzle I'm trying to figure out.
I am working on a system where we have a number of company records saved in the database. Some of these records are duplicates and are no longer wanted/required. 
However, several external systems are still mapping to these invalid records. If we were to delete them entirely it would cause errors to the systems still wanting to get the detail of that company. 
The ideal workflow I would like would be;

The external system looks up Company ID X.

The current system has a table which has a record of all the remapped records, so when the request comes in, the table specifies to redirect Company ID X to Company ID Y.

There are a number of endpoints that could be altered one-by-one to do this - but it would be time-consuming, resulting in lots of repetition too.

My question is, using Entity Framework and .Net - is there a smart way of achieving this workflow?

My initial thoughts were to do something with the constructor for the company object, which repopulates the object from EF if a 'redirect' exists, but I don't know if this will play nice with navigation properties. 
Would anyone have an idea?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Maybe you should use an action filter to change parameter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create **a column with foreign key** for the same table to express the single unique valid company.

For example, you can add `DuplicateOf` column:

```
ALTER TABLE [Company] 
    ADD COLUMN [DuplicateOf] bigint NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY [DuplicateOf] REFERENCES [Company] ([Id]);
```

and express this relation in your code:

```
public class Company
{
    // ...

    public Company DuplicateOf { get; set; }

    // May be useful, hides check for duplicate logic:
    public bool IsDuplicate => DuplicateOf != null;

    // May be useful as well, 
    // returns the non-duplicate uniue company, not a duplicate, either linked or current:
    public Company EffectiveCompany => DuplicateOf ?? this;
}
```

You will have to address `EffectiveCompany` when you want to work with non-duplicate and maintain this column to always point to the correct record. It will also result into additional query, if eager-loaded.

Another idea is to have **a stored procedure** `GetCompany(bigint id)` which will return the effective record - if `DuplicateOf` exists, or record itself otherwise. It will be good for your external systems and will let you hide all this stuff behind abstraction layer of stored procedure. If you decide to change it in future, then you can easily update it without breaking external systems.
However, for you it isn't always convenient to work with stored procedures with EF.

These are just ideas and not the best solutions, anyway.
In my opinion, the best solution would be to get rid of duplicates, update data everywhere and forget forever about this mess of duplicated data.

Comment: I agree that we'd be better off removing things, but the client isn't keen on that! I will give the first solution a try, looks very elegant which is nice. Thanks very much.

Comment: This isn't going to work well in EF LINQ queries because you can't use `EffectiveCompany` in them. An alternative is to map *all* companies, the valid ones to themselves, and always work with `company.EffectiveCompany`. That will turn `EffectiveCompany` into a regular navigation property that translates into SQL.

Comment: @GertArnold Good idea, thank you! Just don't forget to keep in mind this self-reference, so that you don't get into circular dependencies issues, for example when trying to serialize a company.